# VSCode import API to Python project

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a python API that I am using located at "C:\MyAPI" and I am able to import it in standard Visual Studio, but for VSCode I can't seem to find a way to reference that API.

I have been searching for documentation on it, but not really sure how to import the package so that my project can run in VSCode